# Operator precedence issue leads to "error: unexpected type"

Tags: java

Since there have been so many operator precedence questions recently, I started playing with some code and came up with this:

```
int x = someNumber;
int y = --x++;
```

This gives:

```
Error: unexpected type

required: variable
found: value
```

I tried this because I was interested to learn how java would deal with the fact that `postfix` has a higher operator precedence than `prefix`.   This seems like the above statement would lead to a contradiction, which I guess is handled by this error.

My question is two-fold:

1. Why this error?  What does it mean, exactly?
2. Why does `postfix` have a higher precedence than `prefix`?  I'm sure there's a good reason for it, but I haven't been able to come up with one.  Perhaps it would fix this *undefined behavior*, but it would somehow give rise to more problems?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The cause of the error is that `x++` produces a value, and you can't apply a decrement operator to a value, only to a variable. For example if x=41, `x++` evaluates to 41, not to the variable x, and `--(41)` is meaningless.

As to why postfix has higher precedence than prefix, my guess is that it is to avoid ambiguity with other operators while parsing. For example, the compiler can report a syntax error for `x--x` instead of parsing it as `x-(-x)`.

Comment: Great answer.  Thank you.  I never thought of that possibility.  Makes sense.

Answer (score 4):

try

```
int y = 2++;
```

you will get the same error. Post/pre operator are applied on variable not on some number.Thats why you get error

```
 Error: unexpected type
```

Because it expects a variable not some number. Assume your number is 3

```
 int x = 3;
 int y = --x++;

int y become 2++ after applying -- operator on java (as java operator works 
from left   to  right)
```

I don't know  what exactly you are trying to ask in second question. But take scenario

```
  int y = -x---x;
```

here also it will be operated from left to right which comes to

```
 (-x--)-(x) so answer will be -3 so dont get confused by postfix and prefix
```

Answer (score 2):

`x` itself is a variable, it's modifiable, so you can do `++x` or `x++`.

But when you do `--x++`, then `--` is applied on `x++`, which is not modifiable since it's a value and not a variable.

Answer (score 2):

Technically, some entity in an expression is either an "lval" or an "rval".  "lval" is a "left-hand value" (on the left side of `x = y`) and can be assigned to.  "rval" is a "right-hand value" and cannot be assigned to.  You can use an "lval" where an "rval" is called for, but not vice-versa.  `++` and `--` require "lvals".

An "lval" can be a simple variable name, or a dereferenced pointer, or an array indexing expression (and probably 2-3 others).